# Android animating translate property of fullscreen ImageView extremely slow

Tags: android, animation

I am trying to animate a fullscreen `ImageView` in Android which is background of an activity, with two more views. The image view is inside a frame view, which has a negative margin, and I'm animating that. Here is my layout:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-200dp"
        android:id="@+id/mapContainer">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:src="@drawable/earth"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Here is my animation:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="-200"
        android:duration="10000"
        ></translate>
    <translate
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="-200"
        android:duration="10000"
        android:startOffset="10000"
        ></translate>
</set>
```

Here is how I add animation:

```
Animation mapPanAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.map_pan);
View mapContainer = findViewById(R.id.mapContainer);
mapContainer.startAnimation(mapPanAnimation);
```

It animates exactly the way I want it to animate, but it's extremely laggy, around 2FPS, which is unacceptable. How can I make that animation smooth?

Answer (score 0):

The duration of your animation is 10000 = 10 seconds. That might be why it's taking so long. Try reducing this. :)

Comment: It's not too long, I want it to take 10 seconds. It's extremely lagging (frame rate is extremely low) otherwise it still taking 10 seconds.

Comment: In that case your drawable might be really big and the phone struggles to display it

Comment: I don't think so. It's about 2400x1600, pretty less than a full resolution photo that doesn't struggle. I'm really skeptical about that, for some reason, it's trying to redraw itself every frame instead of translating the matrix. It's THAT slow. Could it be?

Comment: 2400x1600 Is really big for a photo. Especially when you are also trying to move it on the screen. Try resizing the image and see how it goes. In my case it would't even display an image that big. But that obviously depends on the device.

Comment: Hmm, so isn't there a way to move it smoothly? The texture is on GPU anyway and the transformations are applied on the GPU (it's running on KitKat, so GPU acceleration is enabled by default), aren't they? It should be butter-smooth if that's the case. Would there the a possibility, like the image being redrawn each time, or the animation is somehow handled by the CPU?

Comment: I don't think so; but then again further research may prove otherwise. Why do you need such big images? For most phone it will probably not make a difference in quality if the image was half the size. You also have to keep in mind that some phones won't even display it. This was my case(wouldn't display an image that big) with a Nexus 5, which is not to bad a device.

Comment: I'll be trying with a lower resolution image, but I'm sure it's possible to animate that too someway (even if it's a very different way than my approach). I want it to be high-res because I want it to be good first impression of my app with a high resolution image on newer very hidpi screens.